# Loading additional modals from server with Paginator.clientPager

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-paginator

I'm trying to load additional modals from the server after the initial fetch with `Paginator.clientPager`

This is my collection, pretty much copy pasted from the example code on github.

```
return new (Backbone.Paginator.clientPager.extend({
    model: model,
    paginator_core: {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/odata/LibraryFile'
    },

    paginator_ui: {
        // the lowest page index your API allows to be accessed
        firstPage: 1,

        // which page should the paginator start from
        // (also, the actual page the paginator is on)
        currentPage: 1,

        // how many items per page should be shown
        perPage: 2,

        // a default number of total pages to query in case the API or
        // service you are using does not support providing the total
        // number of pages for us.
        // 10 as a default in case your service doesn't return the total
        totalPages: 5
    },

    server_api: {
        // number of items to return per request/page
        '$skip': function () { return this.perPage * (this.currentPage - 1) },
        '$top': function () { return this.perPage },
    },

    parse: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.value;
    }
}))();
```

I'm calling the initial fetch like so

```
myCollection.fetch({
    success: function(){
        myCollection.pager();
    },
    silent:true
});
```

Then, after the user has browsed trough the local pages with the clientPager, he probably wants to load in more pages, without deleting the first pages.

I try to achieve this like this, but for some reason, after i call `pager();` the 2 new records are removed.

```
myCollection.currentPage = 2;
myCollection.fetch({
    success: function(){ 
        console.log(myCollection.length) // 4 models, with correct data
        myCollection.pager();
        console.log(myCollection.length) // the 2 new records are removed
    },
    silent:true,
    remove: false // don't remove old records
});
```

What am i doing wrong, how can i load it 2 more pages with the `Paginator.clientPager` ?

I don't want to use requestPager because then i can't do in memory pre-caching, at least, i think.

Comment: It is so quiet in here :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is caused by the **pager()** method of Backbone.Paginator.clientPager. You can take a look at the code here:
[Backbone.Paginator.clientPager](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/blob/master/lib/backbone.paginator.js)

**Lines 292 through to 294** show that the **Backbone.Paginator.clientPager.origModels** is only assigned to the current models (the one whose length you correctly tested in your illustrations above) if it's undefined. The problem is that by the time *the user probably wants to load more pages without deleting the first*, the **origModels** property would already be set as a result of the initial fetch.

This means you'd have to explicitly make **origModels** undefined again before **pager()** would act as you want. Note what happens later on **line 296** of the source code (models is assigned to a copy of origModels). That's why your two new records were removed. The following code should work as you intended:

```
myCollection.currentPage = 2;
myCollection.fetch({
    success: function(){ 
        delete myCollection.origModels; // to ensure that origModels is overridden in pager() call below
        myCollection.pager();
    },
    silent:true,
    remove: false // don't remove old records
});
```